# AWS quicksight and influx db

Tags: amazon-web-services, influxdb, amazon-quicksight

Hi I have an influxDb installed on aws ec2 instance, wanted to show its data on aws quicksight. As I don't see influx dB in predefined data source list of aws quicksight. Will it be possible to create data source for influxDb and show its data on quick sight view. How i can defined my custom datasource for influxdb.
As I know influxDb compatibility is good with Grafana, so not sure whether I will be abel get data on quicksight view. Please let me know if you are aware, how can I achieve it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, AWS Quicksight doesn't support showing the metrics from InfluxDB.
To visualize your metric in AWS Quicksight, simply do following steps:

- Collect data from InfluxDB and store in S3, GlueCatalog, Athena or relational database.
- Show your data in Quicksight from stored data.

Let's see official documentation for more detailed information

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

Not yet a supported database worth using the send feedback setting in Quicksight to see if it is in the roadmap.